# Azure Dev Ops | Git Repo | Do not allow branch to be deleted

Tags: azure-devops, branch

We are using git repositories with our azure dev-ops setup.

I have a couple of branches that I've worked on a lot, but we are having to put a pause on the work for now as other items have become more important. I want to make sure these branches are not deleted accidentally. My permission setup is a little higher than some of the other developers. Is there a way to put a lock from deleting the branch from the Collection -> Repos -> Branches?

Right now I go to `More Options` -> `Delete Branch` and it will ask before it is deleted. I want to put a lock where if you say `Delete` to `Branch feature/testbranchdelete will be permanently deleted. Are you sure you want to proceed?` that it will stop it from being deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested according to your narrative and found that the locked branch could still be deleted.  And after I changed the Branch Security Permission, the test branch was unable to be deleted.

Please use a **new** branch in your Repos for the test of this operation following the marks in the picture below. Define Individual and Group Users as Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags) -> **Deny**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I'm stopping developing on a branch for now and do not want anyone to accidentally delete it!